# Create array key inside foreach loop in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm fetching data from database, inside foreach loop i have to add one array index `list_array`

```
  $list = Lists::where('name',$request->name)->get();
   $Data=[];
   foreach($list as $key => $list_row)
   {
    $list_row['list_array'][]=$list_row['data_1'];
    $list_row['list_array'][]=$list_row['data_2'];
    $Data[]=$list_row;
   }
```

It should be of array type but when i declare it as array it is not working,

> message: "Indirect modification of overloaded property
> App\Models\Lists

Any solution to create `list_array` as an array index inside foreach loop. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not dealing with an array, you are dealing with an `App/Models/Lists` model. What you probably instead want to do is adding a custom attribute to the model. This happens one step before.

```php
// your model

class Lists 
{
   protected $appends = ['list_array'];
    
   public function getListArrayAttribute()
   {
        $data = [
            // your array data from where ever 
        ];
    
        return $data;
   }
}
```

You then can access (without adding it when you want to access the data) the new attribute from within the model, like so:

```php
// where you access your data

$lists = Lists::where('name', 'whatever')->get();
    
foreach($lists as $list) {
    dd($lists->list_array)
}
```

You can read more about the so called Accessors here:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor (Laravel 8)
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor (Laravel 9)

---

I hope I got the intention of your question right. From your question it's not very clear what data you want to add and where it is coming from. There might be other and better ways too.

**Edit:**

Based on the comment from @user3653474 the Accessor function could look like this.

```php
public function getListArrayAttribute()
{
     $data = [
         $this->data_1,
         $this->data_2,
     ];
    
    return $data;
}
```

`data_1` and `data_2` are the column names in the table of the same model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, `$list_row['data_1'];` and `$list_row['data_1'];` are columns of same table i was trying to put these columns in and array so in `getListArrayAttribute` method  `$data = [      // your array data from where ever    ]; ` how will i  add these two columns

Comment: I've edited my initial answer to explain how this would work. Please mark my answer as accepted if everything is clear. :)